# Query ADF to GET data from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are working on an integration between 2 systems where data needs to move between the two systems and to do this, we have opted to include Azure Data Factory. Is it possible that these systems query ADF and get the data from ADF (not ADF querying the systems to get the data)? Example below;

1. ADF gets data from System 1 via an API call - at this point the data is sitting in ADF.
2. System 2 creates a request to GET the data from ADF (not ADF pushing data to system 2).

Is step 2 above possible? Does ADF have some specific API endpoints that can be queried to get the data from them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some specific reason you want to do so? From your description, your case can be achieved by creating a normal ADF flow to get data from System 1 and push to System 2; and associating the flow with a custom event trigger/storage events trigger that is fired by System 2

Comment: ADF isn't a data store, so no, there's nothing to query. ADF is specifically designed to move data from source to sink (and optionally transform data while moving). If you don't want to move data before querying it, you can query the original source (assuming it's a queryable source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data factory will not store any data by itself. It is a cloud-based service that builds extract-transform-load (ETL) and data integration to create a workflow for the movement of data from source system and destination system supported by Azure data factory.

You can connect to both your system endpoints to source and sink and copy data using copy activity in ADF. Connect to system1 endpoint using `GET` method and copy to system2 API using `POST` method.

Reference: [Copy data from and to REST endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#copy-activity-properties)